# iPhone, OpenCV and CvBlobDetector

Tags: iphone, opencv, blob, detection

I found Yoshimasa Niwa's article about blob detection here:
http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en

And something on realtime face detection here:
http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/08/09/near-realtime-face-detection-on-the-iphone-w-opencv-port-wcodevideo/

But what I really want to do is realtime blob detection (like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIgsVoCXTXM) using the iPhone 4 camera.

I can find the headers for CvBlobDetector in cvvidsurv.hpp. But trying to use that without modification is not the right thing to do.

How do I get CvBlobDetector to work? Or is there an alternate solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've followed the instructions to use it properly:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib

One of the alternative solutions i used and it works good is:

http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/